# Javascript cloneNode is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I have few spans:

```
<span name="5">a</span>
<span name="5">b</span>
<span name="5">c</span>
<span name="5">d</span>
```

I use `getElementsByName` to get the span collection:

`var spans = document.getElementsByName("5");`

What I did next is clone the spans and put it into another span container:

```
var clonedSpan = spans.cloneNode(true);
var container = document.createElement("span");
container.appendChild(clonedSpan);
```

But the exception happens saying spans.cloneNode is not a function.

Any idea why?

Comment: `getElementsByName` return a `NodeList`. `cloneNode` expects a `Node`. You probably want to clone the first/unique element within that list.

Comment: use this code to clone all nodes:
`var clonedSpan = Array.from(spans).map(function(node){return node.cloneNode(true);}`

Answer (score 10):

`cloneNode` is a method of an `HTMLElement`, not of a `NodeList`.

You have to call it on a single element:

```
var clonedSpan = spans[0].cloneNode(true);
```

Comment: Please explain the downvotes.

Comment: I think he wants to clone the _span collection_ not just the first (Isn't my Downvote)

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki *But the exception happens saying spans.cloneNode is not a function. **Any idea why?***

Comment: Yes I do, But the answer doesn't solve the main problem...

Comment: Anyway good luck, the post already marked as duplicate..