# Node.CloneNode() not a function -dom-to-image.js

Tags: dom, dom-events, webpage-screenshot, dom-to-image

I want to create a .png file of a HTML page in `angularjs` and download it. For this I'm currently using `dom-to-image.js` and using the `domToImage.toBlob` function and passing the node element to it. But internally when it goes to `dom-to-image.js` it throws the error:

> node.cloneNode() is not a function

Can anyone please assist me here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This error arises when you attempt to call [`cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) on anything other than a single DOM node.

In this case, the error is coming from the [`dom-to-image`](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/dom-to-image) library, which calls that method internally.

Note that without a code snippet, its hard to identify the precise issue with your code, but the point is, when you call `domtoimage.toBlob()`, you need to supply a single DOM node.

So double check what you are calling it with. If you are selecting by `class`, for instance, you could end up with more than one element.

Its best practice to be precise with which node you want to convert to a blob - use the `id` attribute, like this:

```
domtoimage.toBlob(document.getElementById('element')).then(...)
```

where `element` is the `id` of your target node.

Its also possible you're selecting with [`angular.element()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) or even using [`jQuery`](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) directly.

In both cases, this returns an `Object` -- which you *can't* call `cloneNode()` on.

Also note the following from the Angular docs for [`angular.element()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element):

> Note: All element references in AngularJS are always wrapped with jQuery or jqLite (such as the element argument in a directive's compile / link function). They are never raw DOM references.

Which means you would observe the same behavior in both cases, e.g. both of these:

```
domtoimage.toBlob($('#element')).then(...)
domtoimage.toBlob(angular.element('#element')).then(...)
```

would result in the error you see. You can *index* the `Object` before supplying it to `domtoimage.toBlob()`, perhaps like this:

```
domtoimage.toBlob($('#element')[0]).then(...)
domtoimage.toBlob(angular.element('#element')[0]).then(...)
```

and that would also work.

Also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51447846/javascript-clonenode-is-not-a-function) post about "cloneNode is not a function".