# InnerText not working with deep clones in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I'm trying to retrieve some text from a div with the contentEditable attribute and it's working perfectly fine.

I noticed however that deep cloning the element containing the text would make `.innerText` completely unusable, as text layout, such as carriage returns or line breaks are apparently gone from the property.

Here is a working example → https://jsfiddle.net/TomWTG/otuakz6q/8/

Here's the related code :

```html
<div contenteditable="true" class="input_text">
  This is a placeholder.
  <div>
    <br />
  </div>
  <div>
    The issue I'm having is that the linebreaks and the carriage returns are
    completely gone from the deep clone's .innerText property.
  </div>
  <div>
    <br />
  </div>
  <div>Try and convert it to see the text layout removed.</div>
</div>

<button>convert</button>
```

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button')
const inputText = document.querySelector('.input_text')

btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const tempText = inputText.cloneNode(true)
  console.log(tempText.innerText)

  inputText.innerHTML = tempText.innerText
})
```

As an example, let's say that :

```js
    inputText.value =

    "Hello World, foo bar.

     foo bar."
```

the expected output coming from `tempText.innerText` would be :

```
    "Hello World, foo bar.

     foo bar."
```

but turns out to be :

```
    "Hello World, foo bar.foo bar."
```

so my question is : **is there a way I could clone the text and still have access to the both the HTML children and the InnerText at the same time ?**

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: The `.value` property returns a string, hence there's no `.innerHTML` property (`input.value.innerHTML`)

Comment: that's for javascript, isn't it ? because with vue 3 refs, you have to use ```.value``` to access the DOM element say ```input``` refers to, so ```.InnerHTML```, ```.InnerText``` and ```.TextContent``` do work in this situation

Comment: There's nothing in your question that indicates the content of `input` which is one reason for my first comment asking for a [mcve]

Comment: I edited the question and added a reproducible example : https://jsfiddle.net/TomWTG/otuakz6q/8/

Comment: The fiddle is not the same as the code in this question. And for your problem. Markup (HTML) doesn't care about line-breaks (`\n`) characters. If you want a "line break" then -> `<br />`

Comment: I'll edit my post in a minute. What I mean is that I could get with the ```.innerText``` property the linebreaks (\n) of the element, but since I need to clone the text not to see the changes directly, ```.innerText``` does not work any longer (on the deep clone).

Comment: check this, maybe can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51447846/javascript-clonenode-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments basic HTML ignores linebreaks (`\n`).

Exceptions are the `<pre>` tag or elements where the CSS property `white-space: pre;`
is set. Text inside of these tags will show your linebreaks.

The reason why you will see formartted text inside your contenteditable `<div>` is because it actually creates markup while you are editing. Pressing Enter for example will result into an `<br>` tag and so on.

And because `innerText` only gives you the text and not the HTML you will not see linebreaks. The problem is not the cloning, it's the same with the uncloned version:

```
inputText.innerHTML = inputText.innerText;
```

Result:

```
"Hello World, foo bar.foo bar."
```

To solve it you could either use HTML tags that care about text format (`<pre>` or similar) or you just insert the HTML. Using `innerHTML` would take care of your linebreaks:

```
const btn = document.querySelector('button')
const inputText = document.querySelector('.input_text')

  btn.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
  const tempText = inputText.cloneNode(true)
  console.log(tempText.innerText)

  inputText.innerHTML = tempText.innerHTML
})
```